# ARCore viewRenderable with EditText view

Tags: arcore, sceneform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCa15.png)
This is what I want to create. A view renderable that allows the user to input text and upload.

Here is my current code, the button works well but EditText cannot invoke keyboard and input text. Is there some solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance.

```java
private void addInfoCard(Node flag) {
        Node infoCard = new Node();
        infoCard.setParent(flag);
        infoCard.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(0f, 0.25f, 0f));

        ViewRenderable.builder()
                .setView(this, R.layout.description_card)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(
                        (renderable) -> {
                            infoCard.setRenderable(renderable);
                            EditText mContent = (EditText) renderable.getView().findViewById(R.id.card_content);
                            Button mUploadBtn = (Button) renderable.getView().findViewById(R.id.card_upload);
                            mUploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Content is"+mContent.getText().toString());
                                    mUploadBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                }
                            });
                        })
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable -> {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        });
    }
```

Comment: Hey, did you found a solution? facing same issue

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I still look for solutions

Comment: It's a bug, see: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/304